# How to make two LinearLayout, each one take 50% of screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i want to make two LinearLayout, and each one take 50% of screen, there is nothing inside the two layouts, juste color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFE600">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF003B">
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

how can i do it? i wish you'll help me, and thx

Comment: why not have a linear layout with 2 views, both having layout weight as 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a layout like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFE600" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF003B" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Check that, I have used `android:layout_weight` to specify the portion of the screen which needs to be covered by this layout. The two `LinearLayout` having the same weight means the will have the screen equally. You can modify the weights and check how it affects the overall layout design.

If you want to divide the screen horizontally, just put `android:orientation="horizontal"` instead of `android:orientation="vertical"` in the parent `LinearLayout`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks bro! I wish you have a nice day, and thanks again for giving me your time!

Comment: No problem. Great to know that I could help! Welcome to StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep the constraints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FFE600"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline"></LinearLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="#FF003B"></LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

result:
[image]

or if you want to have them horizontally one after the other, just change the guideline orientation and the constraints as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFE600"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"></LinearLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:background="#FF003B"></LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: thanks bro for giving me some time! thats worked for me, i really wanna upvote your answer but i have only 8 reputations

Comment: @Planetofshadows glad you were able to find various solutions that work. no worries about the upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Set weight = 1 in both linear layouts and the other dimension (width or height =0 )  you’re good to go

Comment: thanks bro for giving me some time! thats worked for me, i really wanna upvote your answer but i have only 8 reputations :(